# How to upload image files to ipython notebook for further image processing

Tags: ipython

Instead of working with generated plots and graphs I want to use existing pictures to perform image processing on them.
In [`sage`](http://www.sagemath.org/) one writes:

```
from pylab import imread
image = imread(DATA+"image.png")
```

The [official help introduction](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/htmlnotebook.html) is silent regarding this task / use-case / problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After googleing and trying for 30 mins, I found out, that is actually quite simple.

The notebook has file access to the folder it was launched from. So if one started it in one's `home` folder one can access all the files from the `home` folder directly.

```
from pylab import imread
image = imread("image.png")
```